# Wordpress & Secure Forms

Tags: wordpress

Question on which way to take this project. Im creating a site that is in its simplest, a form that people can submit ideas. I want to have it post automatically to a home page.

Questions is, what is the best software out there to do this? Was thinking wordpress just because I know some php and how I could do it quickly.

Its almost similar to stackoverflow in that you ask a question, add tags to it, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

getsatisfaction.com is a service that allows users to submit ideas or help requests.